# How to load data from api call in card with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native app and I try to navigate to a card component where the data from a backend call has to be loaded. But untill now the data call has not been triggered from the backend.

So I have a service:

```
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

and a context:

```
export const CategoryContext = createContext();

export const CategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [subCategoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [] = useState([]);

    const retrieveCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchCategoryData()
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()              
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveCategories();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSubCategories();
    }, []);

    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                categoryList,
                subCategoryList,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And the component from where I want to navigate to the other component:

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { category: item })}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And then the component where the data hast to been show on the card:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {console.log("test")}
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log(item);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And this is the output from the api call:

```
GET /api/categories/2/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "vogels",
    "description": "vogels",
    "legislation": "",
    "review": "",
    "eaza": "",
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/birds.png",
    "animals": [],
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "roofvogels",
            "description": "roofvogels",
            "images": null
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "parkieten",
            "description": "parkieten",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_gqLXVoK.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "category": null
}
```

ah, oke. I just figured something out.

So if I do this:

```
const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()
                //.then(subCategoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList([results]);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };
```

with this:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item.subcategories[0]} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

Then I see the name and image of one card item: roofvogels.

But if I do this:

```
<SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item.subcategories} />
```

This doesn't work.

And the api call in the console.log is:

```
SUBCATEGORES Array [
  Object {
  Object {
    "description": "roofvogels",
    "id": 3,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_ETI4KPC.jpg",
    "name": "roofvogels",
  },
  Object {
    "description": "parkieten",
    "id": 5,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_gqLXVoK.jpg",
    "name": "parkieten",
  },
]
```

So I try it like:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <Text>{item.subcategories} </Text>
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

But then I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, images}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Question:How to return both of items: roofvogels and parkieten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling the function which makes the api request.

```js
useEffect(() => {}, [retrieveSubCategories]);
```

Try:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  retrieveSubCategories();
}, []);
```

Comment: #RubenSmn.Thank you . But then I get this 'weird' error: Invariant Violation: TaskQueue: Error with task : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Comment: This has probably to do with the data types. You should check if the data from the request is a array.

Comment: #RubenSmn. I updated the post with the output of the api call

Comment: You're getting back a object and passing it to the CategoryList which is probably some Flat or Section-List which expects a array. One thing you could do is `setSubCategoryList([results])`

Comment: #RubenSmn. Ah, thank you. Yes, I get something returned. But the return is now the same as the Parent component - the card from where you navigate to the child. how to show  The names and images of the child data(name: roofvolgels, parkieten)? See my updated post

Comment: Do add a return statement in your useEffect to get rid of API being called on every render

Comment: But how to display the correct properties on the card: name and images?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton On your `CategoryInfoCard` components, are you getting any data there when console logging for example? If true we have to see that component. If not you should probably test if the `subCategoryList` has the correct data.

Comment: @Adii_Mathur the `useEffect` only runs once since it has a empty dependency array

Comment: @RubenSmn. Hi, oke, I edit the post.

Comment: @RubenSmn. Yes, the data is displayed on  the CategoryInfoCard component. But the problem is with the SubCategoryInfoCard component.

Comment: @RubenSmn. Maybe you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585914/how-to-display-array-of-objects-with-flatlist-react-native