# How to display array of objects with flatlist react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native app. And I have a parent child relationship with two components. And a user can navigate from one component to a another component. But the problem is that if the user navigates to the other component the data from the backend is not displayed.

So I have a service:

```
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

and a context:

```
export const CategoryContext = createContext();

export const CategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [subCategoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [] = useState([]);

    const retrieveCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchCategoryData()
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()
                //.then(subCategoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList([results]);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveCategories();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSubCategories();
    }, []);

    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                categoryList,
                subCategoryList,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

and a main component where the user can navigate to a subcategory:

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("categories", item);
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen")}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And this is the component where the name and a image must be shown:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = () => {
    const { subCategoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCategoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);
                    return (
                        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                            <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item.subcategories} />
                        </Spacer>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

and the component SubCategoryInfoCard is just a default placeholder for the data:

```
const CategoryCard = styled(Card)`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const CategoryGroupCardCover = styled(Card.Cover)`
    padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

export const SubCategoryInfoCard = ({ subcategories = {} }) => {
    const {
        name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
    } = subcategories;

    return (
        <CategoryCard
            elevation={5}
            style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }}>
            <Text center variant="h1" style={{ left: 100 }}>
                {name}
            </Text>
            <CategoryGroupCardCover source={{ uri: images }} />
        </CategoryCard>
    );
};
```

But so the console.log: `console.log("SUBCATEGORES", item.subcategories);`

returns this api call. What correct is:

```
SUBCATEGORES Array [
  Object {
    "description": "roofvogels",
    "id": 3,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_ETI4KPC.jpg",
    "name": "roofvogels",
  },
  Object {
    "description": "parkieten",
    "id": 5,
    "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/01-smartest-birds-NationalGeographic_2467639.webp",
    "name": "parkieten",
  },
]
```

But the output: `<SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item.subcategories} />`

doesn't generate the api output but just the default values:

```
name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
```

Question: how to display the values from the api call?

Comment: As you state: `item.subcategories` is a **array**. The `SubCategoryInfoCard` is expecting a **object**.

Comment: Why does the `item` of the `subCategoryList` have a `subcategories` prop? Are those not already the subcategories?

Comment: Yeah thats fine! Maybe even better if you have some kind of git repo you can share so its also accessible for other peeps who want to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252216/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-rubensmn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` on the flatlist has a prop that contains the subcategory items. Instead of **it being a subcategory**. To solve this we can set the state directly with the `subcategories` when getting the data from the api.

```js
setSubCategoryList(results.subcategories);
```

Comment: In this case without curly brackets. Because it is already an array